# Show that the set of zeros of $f$ is discrete

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $\Omega \subset \Bbb{C}$ a region. $f:\Omega \to \Bbb{C}$ holomorphic, $f\neq 0$. Show that the set of zeros of $f$ is discrete. (That is, that it doesn't have any limit points.)

This is the second part of an excercise in which I proved already that given $a \in \Omega$ such that $f(a)=0$ there exist $k \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $f(z)=(z-a)^kg(z)$ with $g:\Omega \to \Bbb{C}$ holomorphic and $g(a)\neq 0$. However Im not being able to see how to show that the set of zeros is discrete. Any hint?

Comment: You need $\Omega$ to be connected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably also showed that you can choose $k$ such that $g(a) \neq 0$.

Then it follows by continuity of $g$ that $g(z) \neq 0$ in a neighbourhood of $a$, so the only zero of $f$ in that neighbourhood is at $z=a$.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from what is referred to as *the Identity Theorem*: if the set of points on which  $f\equiv a$ has a limit point,  then  $f $ is constant.